# VAO Indexing only drawing one line?

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, vao

Hi everyone i'm trying to draw a indexed VAO but it isnt really working.
It only draws the first element (first line).
I made it to draw two lines with only three vertexes but only the first works.
VAO creation code:

```
GLushort indices[] = {
    0, 1, 1, 2
};

GLfloat pos[] = {
    50, 50,
    200, 100,
    500, 200
};

GLfloat colors[] = {
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1
};

GLuint vaoID;
GLuint vboID[2];
GLuint ibo;

trackShader.use();

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glGenBuffers(2, vboID);

glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(GLushort), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

trackShader.addAttribute("vertex");
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(trackShader.attribute("vertex"), 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(trackShader.attribute("vertex"));

trackShader.addAttribute("color");
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(trackShader.attribute("color"), 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(trackShader.attribute("color"));

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
trackShader.disable();
```

Drawing code:

```
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
trackShader.use();
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
trackShader.disable();
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: Why do you keep binding the element buffer every frame? It's *part* of the VAO, just like your vertex attrib pointers and such. You should bind it once in your setup code and leave it there.

Comment: It looks different if you pass 2 to `glDrawElements()` instead of 4? This might be intentional, but the output will look like a single line even if both are drawn because the two lines are connected and have the same direction.